# Datetime is fetched as string in the docker instance but fetched as datetime in local terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, datetime

```
self.cursor.execute('SELECT id, invoice_number, live_start_date, tran_id FROM dbo.invoice WHERE tran_id is not NULL and status in (\'ERROR\',\'PENDING\', \'APPROVED\')')
                rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
                for row in rows:
                    invoice = Invoice()
                    invoice.id = row[0]
                    invoice.invoice_number = row[1]           
                    # On the airflow instance of python, DB call returns live_start_date as str instead of datetime.
                    # So, we need to check the type and process it accordingly.
                    if type(row[2]) is str:
                        print('iam string')
                        invoice.live_start_date = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
                    else:
                        print('iam date')
                        invoice.live_start_date = row[2]
                    invoice.tran_id = row[3]
                    invoices.append(invoice)
```

On the local mac terminal the above code prints 'iam date' whereas in the docker terminal it prints 'iam string'

Any clue? Why? I am also using same python in both local and docker terminal.

Note : live_start_date is date in SQL

Comment: Could be a different version of whichever db driver you're using, or different db library version. Is the OS version the same between the container and the host machine? I suspect not since most folks aren't running MacOS in Docker containers.